# return enddate where cumulative sum of fee column less than 1100 using sql

Tags: sql

```
end date    fee
-----------------
05-Sep-14   700
12-Sep-14   200
19-Sep-14   100
26-Sep-14   300
03-Oct-14   400
```

In the table shown here, I need to return enddate where cumulative sum of fee column is less than 1100 using SQL.

Example:

```
19-Sep-14 (700 + 200 + 100 < 1100)
```

Comment: 05-sep-14 is 700 < 1100. You need maximum cumulative sum

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1
    t1.enddate, 
    t1.fee, 
    SUM(t2.fee) as cumulative_sum
FROM test t1
INNER JOIN tableName t2 on t1.enddate >= t2.enddate
GROUP BY t1.enddate, t1.fee
HAVING SUM(t2.fee) < 1100
ORDER BY t1.enddate DESC
```

Comment: thanks for  answer,
1)can we  output  only max enddate instead of rows.
 2)the rows may have duplicate endates with different fee 

for the below 

SELECT 
    t1.enddate,     
    SUM(t2.fee) as cumulative_sum
FROM test t1
INNER JOIN test t2 on t1.enddate >= t2.enddate
GROUP BY t1.enddate, t1.fee
HAVING SUM(t2.fee) < 1100
ORDER BY t1.enddate


output is 

Enddate cumulative_sum
05-Sep-14 700
12-Sep-14 1000
12-Sep-14 1000

Comment: Order by end date descending - so last end date is first - and then use top 1 to return only 1 record.

Comment: Thanks again and Here extension to the above 
Input table
end date   fee  CourseID
------------------------
05-Sep-14  700    1
12-Sep-14  200    1
12-Sep-14  100    1
19-Sep-14  100   1
26-Sep-14  300   1
03-Oct-14  400   1
05-Sep-14  700   2
17-Sep-14  200   2
17-Sep-14  100   2
19-Sep-14  100   2
26-Sep-14  300   2
03-Oct-14  400    2
In the above table, need to return enddate, CourseId  where cumulative sum of fee column is less than 1100 using SQL.
need for each CourseID.
out put 

end date     CourseID
--------------------------
12-Sep-14     1      
17-Sep-14    2

Comment: that is a different question, please add a different question for it.

Comment: :-) just added with the following subject: cumulative sum in sql with 3 columns returning two

Answer (score 1):

Data sample

```
create view fees
as
select cast('05-Sep-14' as date) as end_date,   700 as fee
union all select '12-Sep-14',   200
union all select '19-Sep-14',   100
union all select '26-Sep-14',   300
union all select '03-Oct-14',   400
```

Solution

```
SELECT TOP 1
    a.end_date,     
    SUM(b.fee) as cumulative
FROM fees a CROSS JOIN fees b
WHERE a.end_date >= b.end_date
GROUP BY a.end_date
HAVING SUM(b.fee) < 1100
ORDER BY end_date desc
```